# How to access a Cordova config.xml preference that has children in Android

Tags: android, xml, cordova, android-intent

I'm developing a plugin for Cordova and I'd like to be able to use the config.xml for some settings like this:

```
<preference name="CordovaGetJSON">
    <api name="uniqueApiName" url="https://api.url.com/whatever" />
    <api name="uniqueApiName1" url="https://api.url.com/whatever1" />
    <api name="uniqueApiName2" url="https://api.url.com/whatever2" />
</preference>
```

Is it possible to do this?  and if so, how can I get that data in Android?

Android adds all the preferences as Extras on the Intent and I can get the value of a single preference like this:

```
cordova.getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("myPreference");
```

But I'd like to be get all the children of the preference.